# Jquery click, show and hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me with my snippet.. I have this code and I don't know what is wrong.. This is my code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="krishna">
    <input type="text" readonly value="krishna" ><br>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</form>
<form id="radha">
    <input type="text" readonly value="radha" ><br>
    <button id="prev">Previous</button>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#radha").hide();

    $("#next").click(function() {
        $("#radha").show();
        $("#krishna").hide();
    });

    $("#prev").click(function() {
        $("#radha").hide();
        $("#krishna").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click next It seems does not go to the next form.. thank you all.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LzpER/ Is this your behavior?

Comment: @Krishna.. Looks like above code works fine for me.. Pls check this ... http://jsbin.com/uqUPipI/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be due to some missing attibutes of your form

**HTML**

```
<form id="krishna">
    <input type="text" readonly value="krishna" />
    <br />
    <button type='button' id="next">Next</button>
</form>
<form id="radha">
    <input type="text" readonly value="radha" />
        <br />
    <button type='button' id="prev">Previous</button>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radha").hide();

    $("#next").click(function () {
        $("#radha").show();
        $("#krishna").hide();
    });

    $("#prev").click(function () {
        $("#radha").hide();
        $("#krishna").show();
    });
});
```

check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EUFc3/)

Comment: Might want to highlight what you've changed as it isn't completely obvious

Comment: thank you.. ill accept your answer and I actually found out that you can also use <a></a> instead of type button.. but i will still use your code.. thanks a lot

Comment: Oh, I just meant make a note stating you added `type="button"` to the button elements and maybe explain why that works

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action, which is the form submit. When you prevent the default action from happening, you will see the desired result

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VG6ge/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radha").hide();

    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#radha").show();
        $("#krishna").hide();
    });

    $("#prev").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#radha").hide();
        $("#krishna").show();
    });
});
```

P.S  I am not sure why you are still using jquery 1.3.x.

Also, check the fiddle for the updated HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

http://jsfiddle.net/GnzWZ/2/

```
$('form button').click(function(e){
    $("#radha, #krishna").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Notes:

- return false is the jquery solutions for preventdefault.
- You can simplify your selectors and optimize your code a little more.
- Avoid making style changes that should be originally made in CSS.

Comment: This would prevent clicking anywhere in the form which probably isn't desired

Comment: Just change the selector to form button then.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is trying to submit the form. So you need to make that button type to button. It is "**submit**" by default in a form.

[JSFidle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S8XUC/)

```
<form id="krishna">
<input type="text" readonly value="krishna" ><br>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
</form>
<form id="radha">
<input type="text" readonly value="radha" ><br>
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but What is happening here that your submit button required post request. So you can prevent this behavior by e.preventDefault() function of jquery. I have updated the jquery code as below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#radha").hide();

$("#next").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
$("#radha").show();
$("#krishna").hide();
});

$("#prev").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
$("#radha").hide();
$("#krishna").show();
});
```

});

visit the following link to get demo on jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/4N95Q/

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="krishna">
    <input type="text" readonly value="krishna" ><br>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="radha">
    <input type="text" readonly value="radha" ><br>
    <button id="prev">Previous</button>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#radha").hide();

    $("#next").click(function() {
        $("#radha").show();
        $("#krishna").hide();
        console.log("next click");
    });

    $("#prev").click(function() {
        $("#radha").hide();
        $("#krishna").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Working fine if you change

> form

in the

> div